# Клиет и Сервер на VB,  ошибка 40006

Tags: windows, vb6, visual-basic, tcp-ip, vba

Пишу простейший TCP клиент и сервер в VB 6.0.
Код клиент:

```
Private Sub cmdConnect_Click()
   sckClien.Connect 'инициализация начала соединения с сервером
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    sckClien.RemoteHost = "q4" 'имя или адрес сервера
    sckClien.RemotePort = 1001 'порт через который будет производится обмен данными
End Sub

Private Sub txtSend_Change()
    sckClien.SendData txtSend.Text 'отправка данных из текстового поля txtSend на сервер
End Sub

Private Sub sckClien_DataArrival _
(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
    Dim strData As String
    sckClien.GetData strData 'Получает данные посланые сервером и помещает в буфер
    txtResive.Text = strData 'устанавливает данные из буфера в textbox
End Sub
```

код сервер:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    sckServer.LocalPort = 2012 'порт через который будет производится обмен данными
    sckServer.Listen 'что бы сервер начал прослушивать порт
End Sub

Private Sub sckServer_ConnectionRequest(ByVal requestID As Long)
   If sckServer.State <> sckClosed Then 'проверка есть ли предыдущее соединение
    sckServer.Close 'если есть, то это соединение закрывается

   sckServer.Accept requestID 'принимает запрос на соединение с параметром requestID

End Sub

   Private Sub sckServer_DataArrival _
   (ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
   ' Декларируется переменная-буфер для получаемых данных.
   ' Вызывается метод GetData и свойству Text
   ' текстового поля txtOutput, присваивается значение переменной-
   ' буфера.
   Dim strData As String
   sckServer.GetData strData
   txtReceive.Text = strData
   End Sub

Private Sub txtSend_Change()
    sckServer.SendData txtSend.Text 'отправка данных из текстового поля txtSend на клиент
End Sub
```

sckClien и sckServer - это элементы Winsock.

Функционал, по нажатию на кнопку, клиент инициализирует соединение, и после ввода данных в textbox они отправляются на сервер.

**Проблема**
После установки соединения(нажатия на кнопку "установка соединения"), когда я пытаюсь ввести данные в textbox для отправки сообщений вылетает ошибка: "Run-time error '40006'
 Wrong protocol or connection state for the requested transaction or request". Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2):

Такое происходит, если соединение ещё не установлено или произошла ошибка.

В код отправки предлагаю написать такое:

```
If sckServer.State <> sckConnected Then ' Проверяем состояние порта
   sckServer.SendData txtSend.Text
End If
```

И ещё: создайте элемент `Timer` и задайте ему `Interval = 100`, `Enabled = True`. В коде формы такие строчки добавить:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
   Form1.Caption = CStr(sckServer.State) ' Выводим состояние в заголовок окна
End Sub
```

По показаниям заголовка формы можно понять, не потеряно ли соединение.